# Les Suissesses sont-elles uniques ?

Tags: grammaire, gentilés

> Les Français sont français.
>
> Les Françaises sont françaises.
>
> Les Suisses sont suisses.
>
> Les Suissesses sont suisses.

Nom et adjectif pour les noms d'habitants sont généralement identiques. Pas pour les *Suissesses*. Y en a-t-il d'autres ?

Comment: Russes? 2345678

Comment: Ah I read that too quickly - you want cases where the noun differs from the adjective, so not russes.

Comment: Pour autant que je sache, « Suissesse » tend à être remplacé par « Suisse ». Sinon, je ne vois pas d'autres cas de ce type.

Comment: Je voulais mettre un tag 'exception' ou 'irrégulier', mais je n'ai pas trouvé. Si quelqu'un a une idée...

Comment: J'ai ajouté un nouveau tag.

Comment: [D'après le wiktionaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Suissesse#Notes), non, il n'y en a pas d'autres, mais ça mériterait de creuser un peu

Comment: Mentions supplémentaires : [1](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_gentil%C3%A9s), [2](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentil%C3%A9#Usage), [3](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentil%C3%A9s_de_Suisse). Difficile de dire sur quoi s'appuie exactement _Wikipédia_.

Comment: Pas une réponse à la question mais une autre bizarrerie: les Finlandais parlent finnois.

Comment: @ho2o2hh2o I can't think of another case like *Suissesse*, but I find it interesting that La Suisse is one of only 7 countries I can think of whose "gentilés" are the same (w/no typical gentilé suffix or other change) as the country's name (l'Argentine; la Rep. Dominicaine; LES Philippines; la Rep. tcheque; l'Union sovietique; & LE Vatican) & of the other 6, only l'Argentine is a singular, one-word, feminine name like La Suisse is. It wasn't done for l'Argentine, but maybe creating "Suissesse" was done to avoid the possible confusion between "la Suisse" (le pays) & "la Suisse" (la citoyenne).

Comment: @PapaPoule Your analysis is akin to an indirect review of how the word is constructed based on usage with the _gentilés_, which I find quite interesting. I still can't really grasp why it ends up being different. Latin something maybe. It's way beyond what I would know. The question should be at +10 imho. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Bon, ce n'est pas aussi tranché que pour les *Suissesses suisses*, mais on retrouve un peu la même dualité avec les ***[Basquaises](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/basquaise) [basques](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/basque/1)***...

Comment: J'avais d'abord pensé aux *[Négresses vertes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_N%C3%A9gresses_vertes)*...

Comment: How about the "Belges".

Comment: @Bazin As far as I know, they aren't *Belgesses*...