# Qu'aurait d'unique la morphologie du mot « Suisse » ?

Tags: origine-ou-raison, suffixes, morphologie, gentilés

Dans un article sur les [gentilés de Suisse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentil%C3%A9s_de_Suisse#Suisse), on explique pourquoi on aurait [*Suissesse*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suissesse) pour le féminin du gentilé et ce, de manière différente de l'adjectif :

> L’explication est que [*-esse*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-esse) est un suffixe destiné aux
>   substantifs : *poétesse*. L'ensemble des formes graphiques est donc :
>
> *Suisse, Suisses, Suissesse, Suissesses* pour le substantif (gentilé),
>   *suisse, suisses, suisse, suisses* pour l'adjectif correspondant, et
>   *Suisse, Suisses, Suisse, Suisses* pour l'adjectif en tête de phrase ou de titre.
>   
> [...]
>   [ Wikipédia, «  [gentilés de Suisse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentil%C3%A9s_de_Suisse#Suisse) » ]

[Ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/41034) on se demande si ce cas est unique. Qu'aurait donc d'unique la racine de *Suisse* ou la morphologie de ce gentilé (ou cette explication) qui fait qu'on aurait ce résultat alors que non avec *Russe*... [*Besse*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessi) ou...  [*Odryse*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odryses) etc. ; en fait je ne comprends pas l'explication : peut-on mieux expliquer ?

Answer (score 1):

L'explication de Wikipédia se base sur le fait que seuls les noms peuvent prendre un féminin en "esse". Cependant, le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/suissesse) recense deux cas d'utilisation de "suissesse" comme un adjectif :

- [Chausses suissesses](http://books.google.fr/books?id=RnpGAAAAYAAJ&q=%22ceinture+suissesse%22%22&dq=%22ceinture+suissesse%22%22&lr=&as_drrb_is=b&as_minm_is=0&as_miny_is=&as_maxm_is=0&as_maxy_is=1950&as_brr=0)
- [Ceinture suissesse](http://books.google.fr/books?id=hPhDHbQC8MQC&pg=PA46&dq=suissesses+-%22les+suissesses%22+-%22aux+suissesses%22&lr=#v=onepage&q=suissesses%20-%22les%20suissesses%22%20-%22aux%20suissesses%22&f=false)

Quasiment tous les articles mentionnant cette particularité indiquent son caractère non-certain (notamment l'article de Wikipédia qui dit que c'est un "cas sans doute unique en français"), ce qui invite à penser que cette morphologie n'a pas d'explication solide. Je me permets cependant d’émettre 2 hypothèses à prendre avec des pincettes :

- Les deux exemples cités plus hauts seraient à l'origine des erreurs de mots qui seraient restées dans l'usage.
- Le féminin originel de l'adjectif aurait été "suissesse", mais son suffixe très atypique dans la langue française aurait fini par disparaître.

Answer (score 1):

L'article « [-esse](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-esse) » du CNRTL (dans son second onglet, qu'on peut facilement rater)  indique en fait que **la terminaison « -esse »** et le mot « suissesse » peuvent aussi être utilisés comme adjectifs, notamment pour **différencier un terme féminin d'un terme masculin se terminant par « -e »** :

> Suff. marquant le féminin.
>
> A.− [-esse s'ajoute à un subst. ou un adj.]
>
> (...)
>
> 2. Le dér. en -esse s'oppose à un terme qui est à la fois adj. et subst. et qui a donc les deux genres (un/une sauvage). Le suff. -esse marque la catégorie du subst. et le genre fém. : borgnesse, drôlesse,  ivrognesse, mulâtresse, négresse, pauvresse, sauvagesse, suissesse, traîtresse.

À cela on pourrait opposer qu'il y a de nombreux cas de nationalités qui prennent la même forme au masculin et au féminin, sans pour autant qu'on soit tenté de rajouter la terminaison « -esse » : Belge, Britannique, Bulgares, Chypriote, Croate, Kazakh, Malawite, Malgache, Maure, Moldave,  Ouzbèque, (Biélo-)Russes, Serbe, Slovaque, Slovène, Tchèque, Tchécoslovaque, Turkmène, Soviétique, Yougoslave...

La Suisse se distingue toutefois de la totalité de ces cas sur un point important : **c'est le seul pays de cette liste dont le nom est identique au nom de ses ressortissants**. Il y a donc une ambiguïté dans l'expression « la Suisse », qui peut désigner soit le pays, soit une de ses citoyennes. Cela pourrait expliquer pourquoi on tend à rajouter la terminaison « -esse », et pourquoi on ne la rajoute généralement pas à l'adjectif qui ne présente pas le même risque d’ambigüité. Ceci est une observation personnelle, il resterait à l'étayer sur une source externe.